# Entity Framework 4.1. Updating an entity. What does this error message mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am trying to update an entity. The code is partially working however, it seems to fail for particular values of `shopItem.GlaId`

`Gla` entities do exist with the ids that fail though.

I cannot see any difference between working values and non-working. The lazy loading works for other properties but not for the Gla property in question.

The error I'm getting is:

**The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "OrderItem_Gla". The conflict occurred in database "PPPContext", table "dbo.Pap", column 'Id'.**

(nb shopItem extends orderItem).

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of this error message.

```
public ActionResult UpdateShopItem(ShopItem shopItem)
{
        var u = db.GetUser();
        var dbShopItem = db.ShopItems.Find(shopItem.Id)
        TryUpdateModel(dbShopItem);

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that table **"dbo.Pap"** has reference to **"ShopItems"** table.

And it seems that **shopItem.Id** that you pass 
`inside public ActionResult`UpdateShopItem(ShopItem shopItem)` is null or empty.

Debug here

```
 var u = db.GetUser();
```

and check **shopItem**

---

SOLUTION:

Make sure that **shopItem** has correct Id or make **ShopItem**  as ***nullable*** object

```
ShopItem? shopItem
Nullable<ShopItem>  shopItem
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no, this is not the problem.

Comment: Just check dbShopItem if it has all fields != null or empty... But as you said perhaps we have to know the ShopItem's structure to make desicion

Answer (score 1):

A kind of silly error, caused by a cut and paste typo.

in shopItem:

```
public virtual Pap Gla { get; set; }
```

it should have been:

```
public virtual Gla Gla { get; set; }
```

In other words I had the type of one of my properties wrong. Well I hope it helps someone else!